# Excluding the nav bar on certain pages in Meteor

Tags: authentication, meteor, navbar, iron-router

I'm trying to create a meteor app where the login page shows nothing but my Welcome text and a sign in through Google. On my other pages I have a navbar. How do I exclude the navbar specifically from this login page? Does it have to do with iron:router? Is there some sort of special method that I call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make 2 layouts like this.

```
    <template name="layout">
    <!-- Regular Stuff for the other pages You can place the navbar here -->
  {{> yield}}
    </template>

    <template name="layoutLogin">
    <!-- Just Login Pages -->
    {{> yield}}
    </template
```

Now the Javascript Code.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'}
            );
});

   //Here we tell to render the template login, on the path /login and use the content on the layoutLogin
    Router.map(function () {
          this.route('login', {
            path: '/login',
            layoutTemplate: 'layoutLogin'}
                    );
        });
```

Tell me if works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the template just for navbar and include it wherever required

```
<template name="top_navbar">
      <!--your navbar code -->
</template>


<template name="mypage">
  {{> top_navbar}}  
  <!-- rest of code for my page -->
</template>

 <template name="mylogin">
   <!-- rest of code for login page  -->
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I set up the two templates and then used the following which worked! The primary layout is the one with the navigation bar and the welcome layout is the one without it.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'primaryLayout'
});
Router.route('/', {layoutTemplate: 'welcomeLayout'});
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

There is much easier solution to your problem, just set layoutTemplate to null for your particular page that you want the nav and other layout to be excluded. In this case we will exclude the navigation for the login page:

```
Router.route('login',  {
        layoutTemplate: '' //the default template is set to null using ''
    });
```